# MDX: Slice by measure?

Tags: mdx

In MDX, is it possible to slice one measure by another?

E.g. suppose I have a cube which includes two measures: Order Value ($) and Order Quantity (#). Can I write a query that will tell me the number of orders with an order value over $1000?

Comment: probably yes - depends on your cube. 

MDX is a full declarative language for extracting data from olap cubes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two ways:

1. Add Order Value as separate dimension and filter out all values which are less than $1000.
2. Add Order dimension and filter them out with a calculated measure.

MDX formula:

```
SUM(
    existing [OrderDim].[OrderHier].[OrderAttr].Members,
    IIF(
        [Measures].[Order Value] > 1000,
        1,
        Null
    )    
)
```